# Move element with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a sidebar with expandable links. When they expand past a certain point I want to move some text from one div to another (red to blue). When I expand and collapse the links, at some point, the text I was planning to move just disappears.

There are two problems:

1. The text should move to the blue div when I expand, back to red when I collapse
2. The text disappears altogether, not moving to the other div.

Here is my html:

```
<div id="sidebar">
  <div>
    <a href="#" class="cal-title">Test 1</a>
    <p class="cal-desc">Lorem ipsum</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a href="#" class="cal-title">Test 2</a>
    <p class="cal-desc">Lorem ipsum</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a href="#" class="cal-title">Test 3</a>
    <p class="cal-desc">Lorem ipsum</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="red">
    <p>Just some random text</p>
</div>

<div class="blue">
</div>
```

Here is the jQuery/js code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    var isExtended = false;
    function placeTiles() {
        // When to move content from .red to .blue
        if ($('#sidebar').height() > 150 && isExtended == false) {
            $('.red').appendTo($('.blue'));
            isExtended = true;
        // When to move content from .red to .blue
        } else if ($('#sidebar').height() <= 150 && isExtended == true) {
            $('.blue').appendTo($('.red'));
            isExtended = false;
        }
    }

  $('.cal-desc').hide();
  // Check how thing are on init  
  placeTiles();

  $('.cal-title').click(function() {
    $(this).siblings('.cal-desc').toggle();
    placeTiles();
  });
});
```

Here is a link to my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awden/2/).

I'm really a newbie at javascript so any suggestion for my code is most welcome!

Comment: Re-reading your Q I can still hardly guess what are you actually trying to accomplish...

Comment: Someone got it despite of my bad explanation. Maybe I edit it tomorrow for future visitors. But I got my answer. Thanks for pointing it out. :)

Comment: Really misses the feature to upvote good edits. Thanks MusikAnimal :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/awden/3/

The problem is that you are appending the entire `.red` element to the inside of the `.blue` element

`$('.red').appendTo($('.blue'))`

Instead, you want to append the *contents* of `.red` to `.blue`, and vice versa. In other words, you want something like:

`$('.red > p').appendTo($('.blue'))`

Comment: Familiarize yourself with Firebug or Chrome's developer tools. These will let you see what is actually happening in the HTML, and would have shown you how you were moving the entire .red element rather than just its contents. From there you might have been able to figure it out.

Comment: Ok I have firebug installed but only really used it for pure css. So try to do that. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think want you mean to do is move the `<p>` from `.red` to `.blue` and back again. To do that, just add `> p` to each selector, like this:

```
$('.red > p').appendTo($('.blue'));
```

and

```
$('.blue > p').appendTo($('.red'));
```